# How to show recently created items if search query is empty in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

How to filter model by one of its properties and if the query string is empty than show last 10 created items? I have createdAt and modifiedAt fields which can be used.

Basically this kind of extended https://gist.github.com/trek/6312601#file-ember-js example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what Trek is doing there, you can utilize the sorting capabilities of the `ArrayController`. If you specify the properties to sort by and access the `arrangedContent` property, you will be returned the sorted content. In your case, specify `createdAt` as the only property to sort by.

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ahaurw01/ZwAu3/2/

To get the first `n` created objects, you can do something like

```
this.get('arrangedContent').slice(0, n)
```

Here's some information on the `sortProperties` usage: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_sortProperties

Comment: thank you! great to see my aproaching to ember has more and more success :)